# Threads from GCD reading old value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My problem is that I'm using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { ... });` to call a method asynchronously, in this method depending on some conditions i set a boolean to `YES`. When this boolean is read in this method, it's **always** read by it's old value which is `NO`.

The weird thing is that when i made a breakpoint on the line where the bool is checked, everything went fine and as intended !

EDIT:
Here is the code where the threads are spawned

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self drawFaceBoxesForFeatures:features forVideoBox:claporientation:curDeviceOrientation image:img];
});
```

The method itself

```
- (void)drawFaceBoxesForFeatures:(NSArray *)features forVideoBox:(CGRect)clap orientation:    (UIDeviceOrientation)orientation image:(UIImage *)image;
{
    if (![self getSendingRequestStatus]) {
        NSLog(@"Sending req");
        // send async request

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
             sendingRequest = YES;
         } );
      }
}
```

Comment: Is the boolean created within the block?

Comment: When the runtime encounters a dispatch call, it takes a snapshot of all of the relevant objects/variables at that point in time. So even if the dispatch call executes later, it will access variables in the state they were at the time of the call.

Comment: @JosephDeCarlo no, it's an ivar

Comment: @Jack: Your statement is entirely _untrue_ for objects. Only primitives have their values copied. The Block
 makes a copy of the _pointer_ for an object, _not_ the object itself; any access of the object will be "up-to-date".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying an ivar that was created outside of a block inside of the block. In order to do this and have the ivar hold the correct value, you are going to need to use the `__block` keyword like so:

```
@interface MyCoolClass : NSObject {
    @private
    __block int sendingRequest_;
}
```

As Jack Lawrence said in the commend above, "[the runtime] takes a snapshot of all of the relevant objects/variables at that point in time". The `__block` identifier will tell the runtime that it should not copy that ivar to the heap and will allow you to assign values to `sendingRequest_` inside of a block, even if that block is simply being run on the main thread.

A lot of good information to start with (including the above) can be found in the [Blocks Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Thank you for the tip and the reference link :)

Answer (score 1):

When primitives are passed into a block they are copied.  So if you put a primitive local or instance variable in a block and then later change it either in the same method that created the block (after the block creation) or another method it won't have any effect on the variable in the block.  In the case of a local variable, just make sure you make any necessary changes before block creation.  In the case of instance variables you could try accessing the instance variable by using some C: `self->iVar` or declare it as a property and access it through the property accessor: `self.iVar`.

Comment: tried making the BOOL a property and reading and writing it using self.iVar, but the problem persists.

Comment: Directly accessing iVars is... Sketchy at best in ObjC.

Comment: @CodaFi Actually, directly accessing an iVar in a block should be fine.  By referencing `self` in the block, the block will automatically retain `self`, so accessing any of it's iVars is as secure as referencing them directly from within the class.

Comment: @SalemSayed Just to make sure, you're not using `self.iVar` literally, but using the accessor name you made?  I hope that doesn't offend, but I've seen people copy and paste without realizing the code was just an example.  Also, if you're sure using a property accessor and still getting a wrong value, then either the property accessor isn't setup properly or the value is being changed by some other code.

Comment: In my opinion the better way to do this is to make sure there's a getter/@property for the ivar in question, then access it via the getter instead of directly.  

Minor nitpick: `self->iVar` is not (specifically) C++. It's just plain old C for accessing the member `iVar` of the struct pointed to by `self`.

EDIT: Didn't see Aaron's newest comment. Good advice there.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen  lol...yeah, you're right about the c++...my brain just skipped. I modified the answer.  I understand that people prefer the accessor, but honestly I'm not sure why.  The presence of self in the block guarantees the iVar will be there...so I'm not sure of the drawback.  The only drawback I see is if you try to pass in a weak reference to self to the block: `id __weak _self = self;`.  Then accessing the ivar through `_self->iVar` is chancy.  But that is a very obvious thing to do.

Comment: @SalemSayed Good :).  I didn't really thing you were, but then it pays to be sure. So I'd check to make sure the property accessor is working fine.  If you're not sure, use a method instead. `- (BOOL) pleaseGiveMeCorrectBoolValue`...or something.  I've discovered that property accessors don't fail.  If they can't find an appropriate method and they're not synthesized correctly, they actually return a default value.  For primitives this is zero (or NO) and for objects they'll return nil.  This has caused me some consternation in the past.